# Creating pdf file in php and then merge 2nd file

Tags: php, pdf-generation, fpdf

I am creating a pdf file using fpdf. This involves 2 steps :

Step 1: I am fetching some data from the database like user identification and other user details and putting those in the newly generated pdf file. The newly generated file is stored on the server upon creation.

Step 2: I have a different pdf file which contains images and a sort of a questionnaire for the user. I have to merge this file to the 1st file. I used fpdf Merge for this wherein path of both files is specified.

The code used to do the following is as below:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
require_once 'fpdf/fpdf.php';
require_once('fpdf/fpdf_merge.php');

$dt1 = "Generated on " .date("d/m/Y") . " at " .date("h:i:sa");
$filename = NULL; 
$filename1 = "/home/server/public_html/qp/1/pdfwork/example1.pdf";

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',8);
$pdf->Cell(40,10,'This is a great world!');
$pdf->Cell(150,10, $dt1 );
$pdf->Output('F', $filename, true); // save into the folder of the script


//now lets merge the 2 files
$merge = new FPDF_Merge();
$merge->add('/home/server/public_html/qp/1/pdfwork/example1.pdf');
$merge->add('/home/server/public_html/qp/1/pdfwork/sample_pdf.pdf');
$merge->output();

?>
```

When i execute the code i get the following error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: reference d'object inconnue in /home/is10live/public_html/qp/1/fpdf/fpdf_merge.php:74
>   Stack trace:
>   #0 /home/is10live/public_html/qp/1/fpdf/fpdf_merge.php(181): FPDF_Merge->error('reference d'obj...')
>   #1 /home/is10live/public_html/qp/1/fpdf/fpdf_merge.php(615): FPDF_Merge->getObject(Resource id #8, Array, '1')
>   #2 /home/is10live/public_html/qp/1/tpdf.php(23): FPDF_Merge->add('/home/is10live/...')
>   #3 {main} thrown in /home/is10live/public_html/qp/1/fpdf/fpdf_merge.php on line 74

But when i merge similar files as the generated one it works completely fine and generates the file.

I am totally clueless in this. Any help and guidance would be aprreciated

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've added your testcode, it seems to be a typo. $filename is an empty variable, so `$pdf->Output('F', $filename, true);` should be `$pdf->Output('F', $filename1, true);`.

Comment: Yes... I made a typo error while pasting the code. The actual code was $filename = "/home/server/public_html/qp/1/pdfwork/example1.pdf";

Comment: The code execution can be viewed here http://www.qp.is10live.com/1/tpdf1.php wherein the 1st file is generated and the second similar file is successfully merged.

Comment: The generated code error can be viewed at http://qp.is10live.com/1/tpdf2.php. The only difference is the 2nd pdf file which can be viewed at http://qp.is10live.com/1/pdfwork/sample_pdf.pdf